# how to block sidebar from scrolling in bootstrap admin theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have very limited knowledge in html and css. I happened to re use a freely available bootstrap template.[This is the one](https://startbootstrap.com/previews/sb-admin-2/) (Bootstrap Admin Theme Template). But I am unable to stop the left side sidebar from scrolling, i would like it to remain static. I tried using  `overflow-y:none` , but doesnt seem to work.

Can anyone guide or help. thanks !

Comment: fyi, the link that you attached is not navigating to correct page. I checked, please link it to https://startbootstrap.com/previews/sb-admin-2/ correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing the overflow from iframe's html using *overflow: hidden* (you can use *overflow-y: hidden*, as per your requirement)

Then to make the any container scrolling, you can assign some **height** and **overflow** properties to it. I have tried my best to demonstrate, hope it helps.

[image: Screenshot with styles that i used to make only the container scrolling]

Comment: Hi , actually I need the dashboard part to scroll and the sidebar to remain static. I tried the inputs from you , but doesnt seem to work.